# Links still use old values after changing model

Tags: angularjs, model, reload, angularjs-ng-repeat

i've got a list of links to change ne number of articles in a product list. depending on the view-type (line or grid) there are different numbers shown:

```
articlesPerPageOps:{
grid: {0:6, 1:12, 2:24, 3:60} 
line: {0:10, 1:20, 2:50, 3:100}
}
 <li
    ng-repeat="count in articlesPerPageOps[viewtype]"
    ng-class="{active: articlesPerPage == count}">
    <a href="#" ng-click="changeArticlesPerPage('{{count}}')">{{count}}</a>
 </li>
```

When i reload the page, let's say with grid view, and click any of the links all works fine, `changeArticlesPerPage('{{count}}')` changes the number of shown articles and reloads the model via http, with the correct number of articles.

then i change the view type to line view without a reload.

```
<ul class="viewList list-inline ">
    <li>view type:</li>
    <li  ng-class="{active: sListViewType=='line'}"><i class="glyphicons show_thumbnails_with_lines" ng-click="changeListType('line')"></i></li>
    <li  ng-class="{active: sListViewType=='grid'}"><i class="glyphicons show_big_thumbnails"  ng-click="changeListType('grid')"></i></li>
</ul>
```

`changeListType('grid')` change the view type and reloads the model via http.

what happens now: all numbers (`{{count}}`) in articlesPerPage-List change, even in `changeArticlesPerPage('{{count}}')` .but when i click the link, it uses the `{{count}}` from grid-view... so 12 instead of 20 for example...

WHY? :O)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the curlies around the count parameter:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="changeArticlesPerPage(count)">{{count}}</a>
```